# Nested routing with routing outlets is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 9.1.7. I want to implement different routing for child components. E.g the graph view  should have 2 router outlets where the upper and lower area of my main content is rendered depending on the routes. Somehow I don't get this right, it doesnt work.

What I want to accomplish is the following. On URI:

**localhost:4200/ or localhost:4200/home**

```
MainContentComponent
-> GraphViewComponent
--> StackedLineGraphComponent
--> CarouselViewComponent
```

**localhost:4200/details/:gameTitle**

```
MainContentComponent
-> GameDetailsComponent
```

Here are my templates.

main-content.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="main-content"></router-outlet>
```

graph-view.component.html

```
<div class="breadcrumb-container">
  <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
</div>
<div class="graph-wrapper">
  <router-outlet name="graph"></router-outlet>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="main-content-wrapper">
  <router-outlet name="below-graph-content"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
{
  path: 'home', component: MainContentComponent, children:
    [
      {
        path: '', outlet: 'main-content', component: GraphViewComponent, children:
          [
            {path: '', outlet: 'graph', component: StackedLineGraphComponent},
            {path: '', outlet: 'below-graph-content', component: CarouselViewComponent}
          ]
      },
      {path: 'details/:gameTitle', outlet: 'main-content', component: GameDetailsComponent}
    ]
}];
```

I think the templates are correct, there must be something with the routes that I'm missing.